# Как добавить в форму регистраций доп.поля Django

Tags: python, django, регистрация

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

   username = forms.CharField(label='Имя пользователя', 
   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

  email = forms.EmailField(label='Почта', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

  password1 = forms.CharField(label='Пароль', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
  password2 = forms.CharField(label='Подтверждение пароля', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Допустим есть такая форма. как мне сделать так чтобы я добавил еще какие-то поля, например фото, поля и тд?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто добавив в форму нужное поле не получится. В твоём нужно будет переопределить модель пользователя. Есть несколько вариантов как это сделать. Если тебе нужно только добавить поля, то настоятельно рекомендую использовать AbstractUser. Почитай эту статью, здесь подробно всё написано:
https://tproger.ru/translations/extending-django-user-model/

Ещё советую почитать документацию django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Вот пример с AbstractUser:

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    # Добавляй поля, которые тебе нужны
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Добавьте следующую строчку в конец файла settings.py:

settings.py

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'
# Указывай название твоего приложение и название модели
```

Comment: До конца ясно не понял, можете показать на практике с моей формой которой я выложил? Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Прости, нет времени. Объяснение: создаёшь модель пользователя (ссылки отправил в ответе), делаешь миграции, и в файле forms добавляешь поля, как username например (добавляй поля только, если они есть в модели кастомной User), если ты добавишь поля в forms, но их не будет в модели User, то данные сохраняться не будут или выдаст ошибку. И ещё добавь модель в файл admin.py

Comment: так мне нужно поля, в котором нету в модели User(( Лан, пока и все равно спс!

Comment: Добавь это поле, я же прикрепил ссылки, перейди, почитай